# PI 3 B+ boots, shows welcome screen then screen fades to white

Tags: touchscreen

I am using the 7" official Raspberry pi touchscreen.
I have checked all of the connections.
When I plug the pi into an HDMI screen it works fine, but if I connect the 7" screen via the ribbon cable then it will boot, show the raspberry pi welcome screen then fade to white.
I already ran apt update and apt upgrade and still no luck. I have even tried other Pi's and other SD cards.

I know it is not a bad screen because if I install NOOBS then the screen works fine until I boot to Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: what do **you** mean by `the raspberry pi welcome screen`? Anyway, it's probably some configuration you need to run in the gui - hard if you can't see anything though - have a look through the question, unless you've been repeatedly asking (and deleting) the same question recently, I've seen the same issue at least 3 other times in the last few days - perhaps there's already an answer!

Comment: Sounds like the Bullseye problem.

Comment: Bullseye problem https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323660

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (Bullseye) and the touchscreen. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323660

There currently doesn't seem to be a fix for it. Your best bet may just be using the previous version (Buster).

Just tested on a Raspberry Pi 3 B v1.2 with the official 7" touchscreen. Reproduced the same problem with Bullseye, Buster worked normally. I used the lite version when testing.